# How replace some symbol with tabulation in intellij idea?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace

Consider a text

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
```

It should be:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
```

**Note** The space between columns should be tabulation not spaces.

I can press ctrl + r and find `,` but what to enter in replace field? If I type `\t` the result would be:

```
Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3
```

Comment: Why downvoting without comment? For me it is not obvious that regexp flag is used not only for search but in repalce too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "regex" replacement, see attached screenshot:
[image]